# Can the Adepta Sororitas bear children?

Tags: warhammer-40k

I have read somewhere (forgot the source since it was some time ago) that the Adepta Sororitas menstruate normally. If this is true and my memory does not fail me, can they have children? Because it would be quite near impossible with all their enhancement and battle wounds.

Comment: Where did you see that the Adaptus Sororitas are enhanced? AFAIK, they are trained and indoctrinated, but not enhanced (as Space Marines are). Note also that not all Adepta Sororitas are Sisters of Battle, so may avoid battle wounds.

Comment: Not as enhanced, meaning the organs, but the training and indoctrination. That's enhancement by itself. But the question is about the whole Adepta Sororitas (including Sisters of Battle).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to a footnote in "Cain Last Stand" Adeptas Sororitas don't take vows of celibacy (and if you believe even part of the fanfic you can find on 1D4Chan they have sex quite often...). So yes, there is no technical reason why they wouldn't be allowed to have children.

You have to understand that Imperial Cult is not as united and monolithic like for example Catholicism (or even Christianity) - there are a thousand different religions with different rules, each one has just one thing in common - the Emperor is the key figure.

Saying all that there is very unlikely that a sister (especially from the militant order) would decide to have a child: They are all fanatically devoted to the Emperor  - they call themselves "Daughters of the Emperor" - (as opposed to the "Brides of the Emperor" during the Age of Apostasy) and being pregnant would (in their own eyes) reduce their usefulness, which is of course sin.

But in the non-militant ordos, as long as it wouldn't affect her duties...

[Here is an interesting discussion](https://community.fantasyflightgames.com/topic/54975-celibacy-in-40k/)

Comment: So, technically they are allowed but most(or all) refuse to do so? Getting the fanfic out of the way. (I tend to hate over-sexualization, over-anything from the communities).

Comment: I'd say that it's simply not strictly forbidden, but still it could be bit frowned upon and indeed sister would rarely decide to have a child.

Comment: The Brides of the Emperor stuff dates to the Age of Apostasy and Vandire's reign over the Ecclesiarchy - the cult originally called themselves the Daughters of the Emperor, were renamed to the Brides when they supported Vandire, and reverted to the Daughters again once they were convinced of Vandire's heresy. The modern organisation definitely don't call themselves Brides of the Emperor.